# Script to add email address to Anti-Spam Policy in Office 365

Tags: security, office365

I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a script to add email addresses to the blocked senders list within and Anti-Spam Policy within Office 365 (Security Admin Centre). At the minute, I have to click through a GUI. It's time-consuming and sometimes the Security Admin Centre takes a while to load. I imagine there's a powershell script out there in the community. 
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a script to add email addresses to the blocked senders list within and Anti-Spam Policy within Office 365` - Yes, they have. Are you asking for one?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was not clear. I am asking for one.